# How rails issue put method on update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, routes

On `edit.html.erb` file, scaffold created, I don't see any code specified `PUT` method. How come the post form call update action with `PUT` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `form_for` function will make its best guess in where to send the form:

Take the following code for instance:

```
<% form_for @user do |form| %>
```

1. If `@user` is a new record, it will send a `POST` request to `/users`
2. If `@user` is an existing record, it will send a `PUT` request to `/users/12` (If 12 = @user.id)

Answer (score 1):

You can see put method on edit when you run

```
rake routes


new_account  GET    /account/new(.:format)  {:action=>"new", :controller=>"accounts"}
edit_account GET    /account/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"accounts"}
account      GET    /account(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"accounts"}
             PUT    /account(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"accounts"} //this is your method needed
             DELETE /account(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"accounts"}
             POST   /account(.:format)      {:action=>"create", :controller=>"accounts"}
```

---

```
<% form_for @user do |form| %> can be <% form_for :user, :url => user_url(:user), :method => :put do |form| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard Rails way to handle updates is to have an edit template (your edit.html.erb), which generates a form that is filled in by the user and then submitted as an HTTP PUT request. Your Rails app should have a model for the resource that is being updated, with a controller that has an 'update' action to accept the form parameters.

If you want to see the data that is being sent in the PUT request, you can use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).